# Receiving intent from activity

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I have one problem. I have my own file explorer and I want to implement functions for in-app file opening (namely images, videos, pdfs and so) and this is my code

```
public static void openFile(final Context context, final File target) {
    final String mime = MimeTypes.getMimeType(target);
    final Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

    if (mime != null) {
        i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(target), mime);
    } else {
        i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(target), "*/*");
    }

    if (context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(i, 0).isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(context, R.string.cantopenfile, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        return;
    }

    try {
        context.startActivity(i);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(context,
                context.getString(R.string.cantopenfile) + e.getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

My question is, how can I make the activities for viewing specified files and how to get intents to it ?
Thank you.
Please use code as answer and if there are any manifest changes please write them. Thanks :)

Comment: What you want are Intent Filters. See this guide: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

Comment: I think you should use onActivityResult http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: Well, I am new to this, but I didn't find what I wanted. My question was how to write that ViewerActivity to open specific file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please add this in your manifest

```
<activity android:name=".ui.MyActivity" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And in your code

```
void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    // Get intent, action and MIME type
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String type = intent.getType();

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
        if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
            handleSendText(intent); // Handle text being sent
        } else if (type.startsWith("image/")) {
            handleSendImage(intent); // Handle single image being sent
        }
    } else if (Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE.equals(action) && type != null) {
        if (type.startsWith("image/")) {
            handleSendMultipleImages(intent); // Handle multiple images being sent
        }
    } else {
        // Handle other intents, such as being started from the home screen
    }
    ...
}

void handleSendText(Intent intent) {
    String sharedText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
    if (sharedText != null) {
        // Update UI to reflect text being shared
    }
}

void handleSendImage(Intent intent) {
    Uri imageUri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
    if (imageUri != null) {
        // Update UI to reflect image being shared
    }
}

void handleSendMultipleImages(Intent intent) {
    ArrayList<Uri> imageUris = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
    if (imageUris != null) {
        // Update UI to reflect multiple images being shared
    }
}
```

Comment: I wanted to know how to handle intent in viewer app

Comment: @Traabefi viewer app? what you mean by that??

Comment: I have my own file explorer. And I am making an activity in it, that will be capable of opening various files. And I wanted to know how to handle the intent there

Comment: @Traabefi PLEASE CHECK MY CODE NOW

Comment: But why are you using action.SEND ? I am using action.VIEW and it works somehow properly. Thanks

Comment: @Traabefi action.send : Deliver some data to someone else.  action.view: Display the data to the user

Comment: This answer is nearly useless, it is only copy&paste from [android dev guide](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html).